# Angular.js. Advice on building an app wide 'modal' that needs dynamic templates/controllers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I need some ideas on how to best approach this. 
In my app I have a dom element, that acts like a modal but pops in from the right side of the viewport. In the numerous controllers in the app,  I need to be able to load a new template into this div and I also need to pass the scope of that controller. So essentially, I have one DIV in my app that can dynamically take a template and a controller's scope.

this is what i am thinking form a high level, and I don't know if this is good approach.
I create a modal 'service' and inject that service into all of my controllers.

so in each controller that needs to pop up this modal, i need to have a method of something like:
modalService.openSideBar(controllerScope. templateUrl);

this is the gist of it but I'm not even sure this will work.
So if anyone's done this before I'd love to hear some solutions!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you be more specific? I don't get this. May be I can help you but only if you be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

This will definitely work, this is how I architect my angular apps.  If you don't have a modal service built already try using the modal from angular ui bootstrap: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Then as you said you would create a modal service and wrap all the logic in there, you can use custom templates if you wish.  But if you want to use custom templates be sure to use the $sce service to trust the html, otherwise it will not work properly.

If you are just using modals to do alerts, I would recommend the toaster library: https://github.com/jirikavi/AngularJS-Toaster

Toasters can float anywhere and are much more light-weight than modals and can also be wrapped inside a service.  Check it out: http://plnkr.co/edit/lzYaZt?p=preview

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, this gets me in the right direction looking at the Bootsrap modal, which takes a template url and scope :)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please [edit] the post and update the answer.